# Is there a way to use Data Annotation attributes in ASP.NET Core to get model validation for the length of strings in an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I want to have an API action method in ASP.NET Core which accepts an object which can have an array of tags. Is there a way to validate the length of each string in the array (like MaxLength attribute) with data annotation attributes or I must write some custom code for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in validation attribute for your needs, but you can implement one yourself by inherit from **ValidationAttribute** e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes and decorate you data model property with it.